# Sum Over the Group of Dirichlet Character

Tags: analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-character

I have the following question:

Suppose $x=q^{o(1)}$, I want to prove the following estimate:

$$\frac{1}{\phi(q)}\sum_{p_1, p_2\leq x}\sum_{\chi mod q}Re(\chi(p_1))Re(\chi(p_2))=\frac{1}{2}\pi(x)+o(1) \tag{1}$$

I suspect the following is true:

$$\frac{1}{\phi(q)}\sum_{\chi mod q}\chi(p_1)\chi(p_2)=o(\pi(x)^{-1})$$
If this is true, the estimate would follow from writing $Re(\chi(p))=\frac{1}{2}(\chi(p)+\chi^*(p))$ where $z^*$ is the conjugate of $z$ and the identity
$$\frac{1}{\phi(q)}\sum_{\chi mod q}\chi(p_1)\chi^*(p_2)=1_{p_1=p_2}$$
Any hint on proving my guess or the estimate is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The last identity should be equal to $1_{p_1\equiv p_2\pmod q}$ instead of what you have written

Comment: @TravorLZH That's correct, but since we are assuming $x$ is much smaller than $q$ writing just $p_1=p_2$ doesn't change anything.